# Meaning of "x has 26 hours in her/his day"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Recently, a colleague of mine and my boss were in a meeting. At some point in time, my boss (referring to me) said "He has 26 hours in his day". It was a light hearted conversation and my boss is a very nice person. I did not understand what he meant. Was it any of the following:

- I have a lot of time to spend at work?
- I am slow/inefficient so I need more time to complete my work?
- I work more than what the usual expectation is?

If not, could you please share your interpretation?

Comment: It refers to [productivity](https://productivityist.com/26-hours-24-hour-day/).

Answer (score 3):

It means that you get more done in a day than most people do. You're more productive than most people. (See the link that Laurel shared: https://productivityist.com/26-hours-24-hour-day/)